# How can I print the original file for all symbolic link files in a directory?

Tags: symlink

There is a directory that contains only symbolic link files.

I'd like to pipe over the ls command from this directory and give it as a factor for the readlink command to print out the original file

I tried the command below, but I couldn't find the answer

```
$ ls opt/integrity/ | xargs readlink
```

Does anyone know the appropriate command to output the original file via ls and readlink commands for all files that exist in the directory

Comment: roaima already says that in his answer, but: [Why not to parse `ls` output (and what to do instead)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: "_I tried the command below, but I couldn't find the answer_" - What happened? What didn't work for you? We can't look over your shoulder so you have to tell us (in your question)

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need to use `ls` to list the files for `readlink` (it's intended to provide a convenient listing of files for people not for machines). Instead you can have the shell expand `*` to match all files in the directory

```
readlink opt/integrity/*
```

Your original command would have probably worked, provided that the path `opt/integrity` existed and none of the source filenames contained spaces (or other "special" characters). But a wildcard handles this already so is a safer solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you  mean that you want to list symlinks along with the target paths they point to, with `zsh`:

```
$ zmodload zsh/stat
$ stat -n +link /dev/*(@)
/dev/cdrom sr0
/dev/core /proc/kcore
/dev/fd /proc/self/fd
/dev/initctl /run/initctl
/dev/log /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/dev/rtc rtc0
/dev/stderr /proc/self/fd/2
/dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0
/dev/stdout /proc/self/fd/1
```

With the ast-open implementation of `ls`, you can also do:

```
$ ls -d --format='%(name)s %(linkpath)s' /dev/*(@)
/dev/cdrom sr0
/dev/core /proc/kcore
/dev/fd
/dev/initctl /run/initctl
/dev/log /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/dev/rtc rtc0
/dev/stderr /proc/self/fd/2
/dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0
/dev/stdout /proc/self/fd/1
```

With GNU `find`:

```
$ find /dev/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf '%p %l\n'
/dev/cdrom sr0
/dev/rtc rtc0
/dev/log /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
/dev/initctl /run/initctl
/dev/core /proc/kcore
/dev/stderr /proc/self/fd/2
/dev/stdout /proc/self/fd/1
/dev/stdin /proc/self/fd/0
/dev/fd /proc/self/fd
```

(unsorted and includes hidden files if any).

With GNU `stat`:

```
$ command stat -c %N /dev/*(@)
'/dev/cdrom' -> 'sr0'
'/dev/core' -> '/proc/kcore'
'/dev/fd' -> '/proc/self/fd'
'/dev/initctl' -> '/run/initctl'
'/dev/log' -> '/run/systemd/journal/dev-log'
'/dev/rtc' -> 'rtc0'
'/dev/stderr' -> '/proc/self/fd/2'
'/dev/stdin' -> '/proc/self/fd/0'
'/dev/stdout' -> '/proc/self/fd/1'
```

`path/to/*(@)` expands to the non-hidden files of type *symlink* in the `path/to` directory, using the `@` glob qualifier. That feature is `zsh`-specific. In other shells you generally need to resort to `find` to select files based on their type.

For instance, in bash 4.4+, and on GNU systems, the equivalent of expanding `/dev/*(@)` would be something like:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find /dev/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type l -print0 |
    sort -z
)
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
  stat -c %N -- "${files[@]}"
else
  echo>&2 No match.
fi
```